# Limitar tamanho de arquivo

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, arquivo, file-upload

Criei um método de importação de arquivo. Gostaria de saber como **limitar o tamanho** do arquivo upado para o servidor.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Uma das possibilidades seria adicionar isto ao `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Também é possível configurar isso no IIS:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/UploadConfig.xml).

Comment: Em um cenário de múltiplos arquivos, este limite seria para cada um deles, ou a soma do tamanho de todos? Eu poderia enviar 1000 arquivos considerando que o tamanho de cada um deles não exceda o limite? Existe um limite para o número de arquivos?

Comment: Que eu me lembre é para tudo, desde que feito na mesma requisição. Se cada arquivo for uma requisição separada, aí o limite se confunde com o individual. Que eu saiba não tem limite teórico de arquivos.

Answer (score 2):

Bom para você poder limitar o tamanho do arquivo upado no servidor, basta você utilizar essa função:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\arquivo.txt");
Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Length);
```

Essa função tem por objetivo retornar o tamanho do arquivo, Apos pegar o tamanho do arquivo a ser upado, Você verifica: se o tamanho for adequado upa, Caso contrário não upa.